# ::で入れ子のModuleを宣言するとNameErrorになる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

下記ともに`hoge.rb`と適当に名付けた1ファイル内にすべてのソースを書いています。

- [ネストしたModule/ClassをRubyで定義する時のコーディングスタイルの話。 - Sooey](http://journal.sooey.com/242)

Rubyの入れ子のModuleの書き方ですが2通りあるようでして、

```
module A
  module B
    def hoge
      puts 'hoge'
    end
  end
end

include A::B
hoge #=> hoge
```

だと問題なく動くのですが、

```
module A::B
  def hoge
    puts 'hoge'
  end
end

include A::B
hoge
```

とした場合、

```
hoge.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant A (NameError)
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

と出てうまくいきません。なぜなのでしょうか？

ちなみに、Railsを使ったプロジェクト(`helpers`ディレクトリ）でこのように`::`で繋げた書き方をみましたが、問題なく動いておりました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

問題ないケースでは、ここでいう`module A::B`の定義より前に、`module A`の定義がされていると思います。質問で引用されたエラーは、`module A::B`のところで、`A`が未定義だと言っています。

Comment: 結局、一気に A::BとAモジュールとBモジュールを同時に作るのはRuby的に不可能ということでしょうか？

Comment: `(A = Module.new)::B = Module.new`とか書くのは可能ですが、それなら`module A; module B`と書いたほうが簡単かと。