# Rubyにとってモジュール定義とクラス定義は同じであるようなときがある？

Tags: ruby

### 前置き

（適切なタイトルが思いついておりません）

[ruby on rails - ::で入れ子のModuleを宣言するとNameErrorになる - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/20153/%e3%81%a7%e5%85%a5%e3%82%8c%e5%ad%90%e3%81%aemodule%e3%82%92%e5%ae%a3%e8%a8%80%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%a8nameerror%e3%81%ab%e3%81%aa%e3%82%8b)
とも関連するのですが上記質問では、未定義なモジュールを`::`で作り出すことはできないという結論になりました。

そこで、今回

#### モジュールを先にちゃんと定義

```
module A

end

module A::B
  def hoge
    puts 'hoge'
  end
end

include A::B
hoge #=> hoge
```

とした場合、問題ありませんでした。

### 疑問

#### 同名のクラスを先に定義

私は以前の質問で、

> ちなみに、Railsを使ったプロジェクト(helpersディレクトリ）でこのように::で繋げた書き方をみましたが、問題なく動いておりました。

と書いており、この部分がどうしても気になった結果、どうもクラスにモジュールと同名のものがあれば問題なく動くのではないかと思って、下記ソースを試してみました。

```
class A

end

module A::B
  def hoge
    puts 'hoge'
  end
end

include A::B
hoge #=> hoge
```

そうすると、確かに問題なく動作しました。

モジュールとクラスの違いがよくわからなくなってしまいました。
モジュールとクラスは別という認識なので、同名のクラスを用意したときにNameErrorにならないのが変に思えます。

そもそも
Aがモジュールの場合、
`module A::B`はAモジュールにネストしたBモジュールということになりますが、
Aがクラスの場合、
`module A::B`はAクラスのBモジュールということでしょうか（クラスのモジュールとは？）？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`module A::B` は A の下にモジュール B を作るということで、A が クラスかモジュールかはどちらでもいいです。

なお、クラスもモジュールの一種です。

Comment: `class A::B`はどこにも書いてませんので、何か勘違いされています。Aがクラスの場合、`module A::B`ということでしょうか？

Comment: すいません、`class A::B` の記述は消しました。A はクラスでもモジュールでもどちらでもいいということを言いたかったのでした。

Comment: なるほど。ClassクラスはModuleクラスを継承しているようですね。Aクラスの下にBモジュールを作るメリットや場面がよくわかりませんが、文法的には問題ないことがわかりました。

Answer (score 1):

moduleはmoduleにネストさせることが出来ます。
つまり

```
module A ; end
module A::B ; end
module A::B::C ; end
```

といった事が可能です。

```
Class.superclass #-> Module
```

となっています。つまりClassクラスはModuleクラスを継承していることになります。
ですから、

```
class A ; end
module A::B ; end
```

と、モジュールをクラスにネストさせることも可能です。