# railsは存在しないモジュール配下にクラスを定義できるのは何故ですか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

## Ruby単体の場合

```
 % tree
.
├── foo
│   └── bars_controller.rb
└── hoge.rb
```

**hoge.rb**

```
require './foo/bars_controller.rb'

bars_controller = Foo::BarsController.new
bars_controller.index
```

**bars_controller.rb**

```
class Foo::BarsController
  def index
    p :index
  end
end
```

### 結果（uninitialized constant Foo (NameError)）

```
/Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/shingo/Documents/raku/sample/hoge.rb
/Users/shingo/Documents/raku/sample/foo/bars_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Foo (NameError)
    from /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/shingo/Documents/raku/sample/hoge.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

## railsの場合

**app/controllers/foo/bars_controller.rb**

```
class Foo::BarsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :foo do
    resources :bars
  end
end
```

**views/foo/bars/index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Listing Bars</h1>
```

### localhost:3000/foo/barsへアクセスの結果

> Listing Bars

## 質問

どのようにしてrailsは`uninitialized constant Foo (NameError)`が起こらないようにしているのでしょうか？

それともRuby単体の場合で何か指定し忘れがありますでしょうか？
過去に
[ruby on rails - ::で入れ子のModuleを宣言するとNameErrorになる - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/20153/%e3%81%a7%e5%85%a5%e3%82%8c%e5%ad%90%e3%81%aemodule%e3%82%92%e5%ae%a3%e8%a8%80%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%a8nameerror%e3%81%ab%e3%81%aa%e3%82%8b)
の質問をしていまして、この質問よりRuby単体ではこのようなNameErrorを避けるのは不可能という認識です。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[6.3 Automatic Modules](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#automatic-modules) に答えがあります。該当部分を翻訳したので、これを読めば理由がわかるはずです。

> If autoload_paths has a file called admin.rb Rails is going to load that one, but if there's no such file and a directory called admin is found, Rails creates an empty module and assigns it to the Admin constant on the fly.

autoload_pathにadmin.rbというファイルがあればRailsはそれをロードしますが、admin.rbがなく、なおかつadminというディレクトリが見つかれば、Railsは実行時に空のモジュールを作成し、そこにAdminという定数をアサインします。